# White background when rotating a webview

Tags: android, webview, rotation

I am trying to "play" with a webView. I slide it and rotate it, and it works fine. The problem is that when I rotate it, I get a ugly white rectangle in the background emcompassing the webview. I tried to change the background color but it's still there, and it's still very white and ugly.
Any idea how I can make it go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extremly strange. While playing around, I tried to modify the alpha value of the webview. Turns out it make the white background disappear! When setting any value other than 1 with the setAlpha method, the white immediatly goes away.

Another thing appear thought : I have a TextEdit just above the webview in my layout, with a black blackground. When I rotate the webview, part of it's corner go over the TextEdit, and this part (on th TextEdit) become white...
I corrected this with invalidate(), but this is really strange.

I suspect both occurrences are bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the background color of the window. You can change it in your theme file

Comment: I tried to change it both in XML and in Java code, nothing works.

Comment: Have u set the window color in the overall app theme? This is the way I suggested u

Comment: This is not to do in the layout XML file

Comment: I tried to use Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar for the activity holding the webview, if that's what you mean. No change

Comment: Not really. Here is an example how to write your own app theme: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I tried a lot of things around that idea, nothing changes that white.